# Injetar $state (ui-router) dentro $http interceptor está causando erro de dependência circular, como resolver?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routes

**Oque eu preciso:**

Eu preciso que quando o http request retorne o error 401 ou 403 o usuário seja redirecionado para tela de login.

**Problema:**
O problema acontece quando eu injeto o $state na minha factory, causa o error de dependência circular:

> **Uncaught Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: $http <- $templateFactory <- $view <- $state <- InterceptorRequestFactory <-
>   $http <- $translatePartialLoader
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.9/$injector/cdep?p0=%24http%20%3C-%20%24tem…erceptorRequestFactory%20%3C-%20%24http%20%3C-%20%24translatePartialLoader**

**Código:**

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.factory')
    .factory('InterceptorRequestFactory', InterceptorRequestFactory);

  function InterceptorRequestFactory($q, $state) {
    return{
      request: function(config){
        return config;
      },
      requestError: function(rejection){
        console.log(rejection);
        return $q.reject(rejection);
      },
      response: function(response){
        return response
      },
      responseError: function(rejection){
        console.log(rejection);
        if(rejection.status === 401 || rejection.status === 403){
          $state.go('app.login');              
        }
        else{
        return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
      }
    };
  }

})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para corrigir o problema basta injetar o `$state` manualmente utilizando o serviço `$injector`, abaixo um exemplo visto em [uma resposta do SoEn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20230691/injecting-state-ui-router-into-http-interceptor-causes-circular-dependency):

```
var interceptor = ['$location', '$q', '$injector', function($location, $q, $injector) {
    function success(response) {
        return response;
    }

    function error(response) {

        if(response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {
            $injector.get('$state').transitionTo('public.login');
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
        else {
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    }

    return function(promise) {
        return promise.then(success, error);
    }
}];

$httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(interceptor);
```

O problema ocorre porque o [angular-ui-route](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) injeta o service `$http` como dependência dentro do `$templateFactory`, e isso cria uma referencia circular para $http com o `$httpProvider`. Por isso devemos realizar a injeção manualmente.

Este problema também acontecerá se você tentar injetar o serviço $http, conforme exemplificado na resposta do Jonathan Palumbo:

```
var interceptor = ['$location', '$q', '$http', function($location, $q, $http)
```